# Is it possible to access a tab item from one form to another in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new to WPF/XAML and not by choice. Just inherited a little app that I want to improve but the WPF/XAML side of it is kicking my butt (I can handle the C# just fine).

For example, I have this in the MainWindow XAML:

```
<TabControl x:Name="charTabs" Margin="10,4,10,10" Grid.Row="1" >
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

in the MainWindow.cs code I have

````
charTabs.Items.Add(new TabItem```{Header = name,
Content = new Character(save, fs, br, i);
````

That code fills up an inner form with the tabs. The XAML for the second window within the main window is significantly large, so I'm only posting here the part I think is relevant:

```
<Grid>
<StackPanel>
    <GroupBox Header="General">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,4,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox x:Name="charName" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" MaxLength="28" AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="False" TextChanged="charName_TextChanged"/>
```

And in the C# code I have the following, which doesn't work because it can't reach the Tabs component. That's what I'm trying to do. Is it possible or is it impossible?

```
private void charName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MainWindow.charTabs.Items[charIndex] = charName.Text; //this doesn't work}
```

I've tried things that I've done in WinForms like passing the form as a variable to the other form, always ends up null for some reason. Just trying the code above doesn't work either. I've Google and read other StackOverflow posts with no luck. I'm hoping this is possible. Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

```
var character = new Character(save, fs, br, i, isPS3 ? charBasesPS3 : charBasesA, isPS3 ? charBasesPS3 : charBasesB, isPS3);
charTabs.Items.Add(new TabItem
{
    Header = name,
    Content = character,
});
character.mainWindow = this;
```

Gives me access to mainWindow.charTabs.Items. However, there doesn't seem to be a method to change the header/name/title of the tab item. If I do this:

```
mainWindow.charTabs.Items[charIndex] = charName.Text;
```

It blanks out all the content of that Tab, and names it what I wanted to name it and also inserts that same text as the only content of the tab. So I guess I have my answer since there is no method to rename/relabel the tab but instead it overwrites the tab contents.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mainWindow.charTabs.Items[charIndex].Header = charName.Text;` ?
`charTabs` is a TabControl `charTabs.Items[charIndex]` should be a TabItem so if you want to change the Header you have to look for the Header property ?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It says "'object does not contain a definition for 'Header' and no accessible extension method 'Header' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found"

Comment: The error message says that it has the type `object` so you probably have to cast it to TabItem first. It probably still is a TabItem.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

((TabItem)(mainWindow.charTabs.Items[charIndex])).Header = charName.Text;